# Forgot line break. Split line by number of columns

Tags: sed, awk, text-editing, newlines

I am sending a single line of output (from some cluster jobs) to a file. The output has a defined number of columns, but I forgot to add a line break at the end of each line, so all my input is being concatenated into a single long line in the output file.

**How can I wrap the output to a set number of columns?**

e.g. I have:

```
Alice   1   2   3   Barry   4   5   6   Charlie 7   8   9
```

I would like:

```
Alice   1   2   3
Barry   4   5   6
Charlie 7   8   9
```

As fas as I can tell `awk` operates on lines, and has no way to operate over the current field number within a record, and `fold` works on fixed column widths. You can assume that there is a single delimiter between each field which is always the same (`\t`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the name of the file is **xyz.txt**
Then you could try these:

**sed -i -e '$a\' xyz.txt**

or

**echo Good\\nline2Morning**  then the output will be:

Good

Morning

or

**echo "`date` User `whoami` started the script."$'\r' >> xyz.txt**

Here the $'\r' at the end is an extra carriage-return; it, plus the Unix line ending, will result in a Windows line ending.

Please let me know, if I understand your question correctly.

Please refer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741433/appending-a-line-break-to-an-output-file-in-a-shell-script)**.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying, but you've misunderstood. I already have a file with a single line of output. This single line file needs to be broken into multiple lines, at every 4th field. Cheers